# Writing a Module Which Prevent Overwriting Previous Data in RAM

Tags: vhdl, ram

### The Problem

I have a channel which contains a 512 deep piece of RAM. I have a control block which tells this channel when to write and when to read. When it writes, the write pointer will increase linearly over each clock cycle so long as the capture flag is held high.

I can't use a FIFO for this as I may have to read out of the same address twice. I just want to raise a flag when the write address is close to the read address (i.e some kind of "high water mark" - a value which will be set later). The problem is the wrap around makes this difficult. So when I am reading from address 500 but writing to address 0, this is going to play havoc with my equality signs below. Another bad scenario is if it reads from address 0, then from 511, then from 0 again, I'm unsure how to deal with making the signs flip. I can't think of a simple way of solving this.

Can anyone think of a more efficient way of dealing with this as I'm sure it's been done before?

### My Attempt

```
SIGNAL actr, read_addr, s_hwm, s_lwm, hwm, lwm : unsigned(8 downto 0);

process(clk_p)
BEGIN
    IF RISING_EDGE(clk_p) THEN
        IF rst_i = '1' THEN
            s_hwm <= (OTHERS => '0'); -- high water mark
            s_lwm <= (OTHERS => '0'); -- low water mark
        ELSE
            s_hwm <= read_addr - hwm; -- when it reads, know the relative high water mark from the read pointer
            s_lwm <= read_addr - lwm;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

PROCESS(clk_p)
BEGIN
    IF RISING_EDGE(clk_p) THEN
        IF rst_i = '1' THEN
            ram_state <= ST_IDLE;
        ELSE

            CASE ram_state IS
                WHEN ST_IDLE =>
                    IF actr >= s_hwm then -- actr is the current write pointer
                        ram_state <= ST_WARN; -- WARN when it is close to the high water mark
                    END IF;
                WHEN ST_WARN =>
                    IF actr >= read_addr THEN -- read_addr is the current address it is reading out from, if the write pointer goes over this, this it is overwriting old data
                        ram_state <= ST_FULL;
                    ELSIF actr <= s_lwm THEN -- exit the warn when it is below the low water mark and enough reads have been initiated
                        ram_state <= ST_IDLE;
                    END IF;
                WHEN ST_FULL =>
                    ram_state <= ST_FULL;
            END CASE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

END rtl;
```

Comment: Can you use a transactional fifo? For example a fifo with commit and rollback signals on the read side can reset the readpointer to the last commit point. If you have read your data twice, commit it and the writepointer can use the new space. Implementation example [PoC.fifi_cc_got_tempgot]( https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/fifo/fifo_cc_got_tempgot.vhdl).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting comment, but something I did not mention is there are certain constraints and other reasons which results in me not being allowed to implement a FIFO in the channel I described but needs to be RAM (the code/scenario is very much simplified above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know your write pointer is always ahead of your read, you can easily solve the problem with a code like this:

```
tmp := ('1' & write_ptr) - read_ptr;
count <= tmp(count 'range);

-- Alternate syntax without tmp variable using numeric_std
count <= resize(('1' & write_ptr) - read_ptr, count'length);
```

So, if read is at 500 and write at 0, this gives you `512-500 = 12`. And if write is at 500 and read at 0, it gives you `512+500-0 = 912 = 500` since you drop the msb.

Another way is to keep track of occupancy through a counter controlled by your rd/wr signal.

```
if rd = '1' and wr = '0' then
    count <= count - 1;
elsif wr = '1' and rd = '0' then
    count <= count + 1;
end if;
```

That way, you don't have to bother about the actual values of your pointers.

Comment: The second method won't work incase I read out of the same address twice, it'd go out of sync.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the first method. If I run the numbers for `read=500` and `write=0` then:

`tmp = ('1' & 500) - 0 = 1012-0 = 1012`, If you drop the msb from this, it becomes `500`.

`tmp = ('1' & 0 ) - 500 = 2 - 500 = 498 `, If you drop the msb it becomes `242`

Comment: It's 512, not 1024. Also ,it's the other way around, ('1' & write), not ('1' & read). The operation I gave gives how much write is ahead of read. You seem to be confused by bit concatenation, ('1' & ptr) yield a 10 bits vector with msb = 1, lsbs equal ptr. The resulting vector is always equal to ptr+512.

Comment: Ahh sorry I misunderstood the fact you were subtracting the count from thre RAM size. Clever, thankyou =D